# getAttributes() from product returns old results in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Fetching attributes for a different product results in old data, see:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
```

-> count: 50 (correct)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
```

-> count: 70 (correct)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
```

-> count: 50 -> wrong, this is from the first product! why???

Magento version is 1.9.2.4

Comment: use `getSize()` insted of `count()`